# generate skeleton classes that mirror a java library

Tags: java, jar, mocking, bytecode, stub

I have a java library without sources, and I want to generate skeleton classes that mirror the public api of that library.

Given a compiled jar file, how can I generate code for the public classes, interfaces and enums, with stubs for the public methods and fields, ideally preserving annotations?

The generated classes should contain no decompiled code aside from the public api.

Ideally I am looking for a way that does not involve decompiling the java library at all, as I am a bit unsure about the license ramifications that would entail.